# IBM Watson Tone Analyzer API with Swift

Tags: json, analyzer

I am working with IBM Watson Tone Analyzer API using Swift. I tried the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        print("hello")
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let username = "USERNAME"
        let password = "PASSWORD"
        let versionDate = "2016-05-19" // use today's date for the most recent version
        let service = ToneAnalyzer(username: username, password: password, version: versionDate)

        let failure = { (error: NSError) in print(error) }
        service.getTone("Text that you want to get the tone of", failure: failure) { responseTone in
            print(responseTone.documentTone)
        }

    }
```

For this, I am getting the following error:
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6004 "Data could not be serialized. Failed to parse JSON response. No error information was provided during serialization." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Data could not be serialized. Failed to parse JSON response. No error information was provided during serialization.}

I read the documentation but it does not help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using some kind of library? If so the most likely cause is the version number has changed and you need to set that. [More details about that here](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/tone-analyzer/api/v3/#post-tone).

Here is some sample code I did that works (forgive me, my Swift knowledge is pretty basic).

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
var username = "<SERVICE USERNAME HERE>"
var password = "<SERVICE PASSWORD HERE>"
var endpoint = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2016-05-19&text="

var sampleText = "I am really excited to be working with Watson!"

// -------------------------------------------------------------------

var authString = username + ":" + password
var authData = authString.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)
var authValue = "Basic " + authData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

var toneUrl = endpoint + sampleText.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
let url = NSURL(string: toneUrl)

let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authValue]
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

var taskIsRunning = true;
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
    (let data, let response, let error) in
    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)

            // Work with JSON object.
        }
        catch {
            print("Problem serialising JSON object")
        }
    }
    taskIsRunning = false
}

task.resume()
while (taskIsRunning) {
    sleep(1)
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Do let me know how did you go about it (documentation/videos)? I am similarly trying to use Personality Insights and other APIs

Comment: I work in Watson group. You will find the code above should work for any of the other services (GET calls) with a little modification. The related service API docs tend to have samples you can use.